# Interpolation in PHP for chef automation

Tags: php, wordpress, chef, ruby, chef-solo

Hi I am using chef for deployment automation of a wordpress site where in I need to read `database`, `host`, `username` and `password` from my `shared.yml` for `wp-config.php` so I am trying below code in my template file

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', '"<%= @database %>"');
define('DB_USER', '"<%= @username %>"');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '"<%= @password %>"');
define('DB_HOST', '"<% @host %>"');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
?>
```

however the interpolation isn't taking place in where it should take actual values that are defined in `_shared.yml`.  My attributes in chef looks like below.

```
default[:example_wp][:database][:host]          = ""
default[:example_wp][:database][:adapter]       = "mysql2"
default[:example_wp][:database][:database]      = "wordpress"
default[:example_wp][:database][:username]      = "wordpress"
default[:example_wp][:database][:password]      = ""
```

Can someone help with interpolation that I am trying.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple SE sites

Comment: Answered over in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929709/interpolation-in-php-for-chef-automation

Comment: @coderanger Why? It's on topic here, not there.

Comment: Because the vast bulk of Chef questions, and thus people that answer them are on SO. Just compare the tag activity here vs. there. As you can see in my answer there, it's definitely a programming topic :)